# How to display transactions in ‘developer.paypal.com’

Tags: paypal

I wrote my PayPal payments app using REST API SDK for PHP from GitHub.

In ‘developer.paypal.com’ there is a button labeled "Create App", I gave an application name which was immediately approved, and from the created App I’m using in my code the “Client ID” and “Secret”.

The code seems to work correctly, and from ‘developer.paypal.com’ I can ‘Enter Sandbox site’ to view transactions of my ‘Sandbox test accounts’.

My problem is that in ‘developer.paypal.com’ the link ‘Transactions’ doesn't display transactions.

Sandbox => Transactions, direct me to (page title): Test REST API transactions

Live => Transactions, direct me to (page title): Live REST API transactions and responses

In both cases above, instead of getting transactions, I get a page with a link to “Create your first PayPal app and receive API credentials.”

How to display and get detail transactions on ‘developer.paypal.com’?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good idea to try logging out and logging back in. Sometimes, the cache might be causing this to happen. Let me know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: nope... even restart the computer doesn't help here.